# Nested Groovy closures produce StackOverflowException

Tags: groovy, closures

Why the following code produce StackOverflowException?

```
​Closure c0 = { 
  println "$this $owner $delegate"
  Closure c1 = {
    println "$this $owner $delegate"
  }
  c1()
}

c0()​
```

And the output is

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy:5)
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:7)
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy:5)
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StackOverFlowError is being caused by failed string interpolation of the inner closure's ***owner*** and ***delegate*** objects.

You can access their values with string concatenation instead of string interpolation.

In the inner Closure c1, you can do:

```
println "$this " + owner + " " + delegate
```

Here's a [link to an example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTmk2dVZvME8tdnc) that implements this solution and also dumps out the contents of 'this', 'owner' and 'delegate' for both the inner and outer closure so you can see how they are different.

Visit the link and click the 'execute' button to see the results.

Comment: Thank you, I guess you answered to my question

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to see what is going on if you decompose the script like this:

```
Closure c0 = {
  println "$this"
  println "$owner"
  println "$delegate"
  Closure c1 = {
    println "$this"      // breakpoint here
    println "$owner"
    println "$delegate"
  }
  c1()
}

c0()
```

then set a breakpoint in your IDE as indicated, and run it through the debugger. Then you can see that the `owner` and `delegate` values in the inner closure are, in fact, the outer closure.

Now, normally, when an object is interpolated into a Groovy GString, the `toString()` method is invoked, but that is not the case when the interpolated object is a closure. In *that* case, the invocation sequence is `object.call().toString()`. Thus, closures `c1` and `c0`end up invoking each other in an infinite loop.

In a debugger you could step through and see this effect in action, stepping from my line 7 back to my line 2 (to invoke the `owner`, `c0`), then 3, 4, 5 (to define `c1`), 10 (to invoke `c1`), 6, 7, and back to 2 again.

To prevent this, coerce the closures to string more directly, like this:

```
    println (owner as String)
```

or this:

```
    println (owner.toString())
```

or this:

```
    println ("" + owner)
```

(as in trevor's solution)